# How find address of specific pool allocated?

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg, kernel-mode

How find address of specific pool that allocated by specific tag

e.g. address of pool that allocated by CM7 tag?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [WinDbg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinDbg), you can use the [`!poolfind`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff564696.aspx) command:

> The **!poolfind** extension finds all instances of a specific pool tag in
>   either nonpaged or paged memory pools.
>
> ...
>
> ```
> kd> !poolfind SeSd 0
>
> Scanning large pool allocation table for Tag: SeSd (827d1000 : 827e9000)
>
> Searching NonPaged pool (823b1000 : 82800000) for Tag: SeSd
>
> 826fa130 size:   c0 previous size:   40  (Allocated) SeSd
> 82712000 size:   c0 previous size:    0  (Allocated) SeSd
> 82715940 size:   a0 previous size:   60  (Allocated) SeSd
> 8271da30 size:   c0 previous size:   10  (Allocated) SeSd
> 82721c00 size:   10 previous size:   30  (Free)      SeSd
> 8272b3f0 size:   60 previous size:   30  (Allocated) SeSd
> 8272d770 size:   60 previous size:   40  (Allocated) SeSd
> 8272d7d0 size:   a0 previous size:   60  (Allocated) SeSd
> 8272d960 size:   a0 previous size:   70  (Allocated) SeSd
> ```

Comment: when is use !poolfind output is: Unable to get MmSystemRangeStart !!! on loop